# How to merge multiple tables in MYSQl which have two columns in common

Tags: mysql, sql

I have four tables table_1, table_2, table_3 and table_4. All the four of them have columns like this:

```
table_1: age_grp, gender, height;
table_2: age_grp, gender, weight;
table_3:  age_grp, gender, shoesize;
table_4: age_group, gender, BMI;
```

I would like to create a new table with columns:

```
age_grp, gender, height, weight, shoesize, BMI
```

I want only those columns to be merged where `age_grp and gender` is same in all tables. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This easily can be doen via [`INNER JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html):

```
SELECT table_1.*, table_2.*, table_3.*, table_4.* FROM table_1  
  INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_1.age_grp = table_2.age_grp  
    AND table_1.gender = table_2.gender
  INNER JOIN table_3 ON table_2.age_grp = table_3.age_grp  
    AND table_2.gender = table_3.gender
  INNER JOIN table_4 ON table_3.age_grp = table_4.age_grp  
    AND table_3.gender = table_4.gender
```

You can `JOIN` any table with any, if you have a requirement that all the data in all tables have same values in the columns.

Note that you shouldn't use `*` in real production script, use the column names explicitly.

Comment: for the third and fourth, can i just add the names after commas?

Comment: @VMAtm I have similar query, wanted to optimize LINQ query

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee You should ask a different question as you are using the LINQ. But `JOIN`s can't be optimized easilly.

Comment: @VMAtm isn't is possible to go to take this conversation to chat?

Comment: @VMAtm Thanks a lot. Please don't mind me asking this but I just have one small query. Now i don't want the age_grp and gender to occur multiple times. I mean now the new slection has rows like `age_grp` `gender` `height` `age_grp` `gender` `weight` etc.

Comment: @Morpheus 
`SELECT table_1.*, table_2.wieght, table_3.shoesize, table_4.BMI`

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee, thanks. Even i figured it out exactly just now.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good chance you aren't going to get the results you want by a pure match. For example, the following will create the table you describe:

```
insert into newtable 
    select t1.age_grp, t1.gender, t1.height, t2.weight, t3.shoesize, t4.BMI 
    from table_1 t1 
    inner join table_2 t2 on t1.age_grp = t2.age_grp 
        and t1.gender = t2.gender
    inner join table_3 t3 on t1.age_grp = t3.age_grp 
        and t1.gender = t3.gender
    inner join table_4 t4 on t1.age_grp = t4.age_grp 
        and t1.gender = t4.gender;
```

The problem is if *ANY* of the items fail, you don't get a row. You might consider using outer join instead.

Answer (score 1):

In spite of this request being answered already, I'd like to add an answer for the case of missing values, e.g. only shoesize not given for an age_grp/gender pair.

For a solution with joins you would need FULL OUTER JOINs which MySQL doesn't support. And mimicking this with LEFT and /or RIGHT OUTER JOINs can be a pain with several tables.

Here is a solution using UNION ALLs and a final aggregation instead.

```
create table mytable as
select age_grp, gender, max(height) as height, max(weight) as weight, max(shoesize) as shoesize, max(bmi) as bmi
from
(
  select age_grp, gender, height, cast(null as unsigned integer) as weight, cast(null as unsigned integer) as shoesize, cast(null as unsigned integer) as bmi from table_1
  union all
  select age_grp, gender, cast(null as unsigned integer) as height, weight, cast(null as unsigned integer) as shoesize, cast(null as unsigned integer) as bmi from table_2
  union all
  select age_grp, gender, cast(null as unsigned integer) as height, cast(null as unsigned integer) as weight, shoesize, cast(null as unsigned integer) as bmi from table_3
  union all
  select age_group, gender, cast(null as unsigned integer) as height, cast(null as unsigned integer) as weight, cast(null as unsigned integer) as shoesize, bmi from table_4
) x
group by age_grp, gender;
```

I was surprised that `CAST(NULL AS INT)` results in a syntax error, btw. I had to change it to `CAST(NULL AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)`.

SQL fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4fa5c/1.